# Looking for JavaScript lib that implements RRULE (iCalendar RFC 5545)

Tags: html, javascript, icalendar, rrule, rfc5545

I am looking for a good iCalendar RFC 5545 processing library (open source / GPL compatible) that has been implemented in JaavScript. My current interest is a js library that fully implements the RRULE so that we can use our calendar web app offline with HTML5 compatible browsers.

We have our UI so just a usable library that can generate the RRULE and the event dates is what we need. I've even give some thought to contacting the guy that created the python dateutil to see if we could port his library to js.

Examples of our needs include:

1. Given raw data (provided by our existing UI), construct iCalendar VEVENT information including RRULEs.
2. Given a VCALENDAR / VEVENT object, generate the appropriate iCalendar text string that I can store locally using HTML5 until the client connects to the server.
3. Given a VCALENDAR / VEVENT object with RRULEs in it, be able to say "give me the start/end dates of the next X occurrences from some date" or "give me all the start/end dates of occurrences until date Y".

Any leads, thoughts or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery Plugin which implements iCalendar with RFC2245: http://keith-wood.name/icalendar.html

.NET library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/

PDF with information about a 4D Ajax Frameworks that uses iCal: ftp://ftp.4d.com/ACI_PRODUCT_REFERENCE_LIBRARY/4D_PRODUCT_DOCUMENTATION/PDF_Docs_by_4D_Product_A-Z/4D_Web_2.0_Pack/v11_R5/4DAF_Cal4D_Guide_v11.5.pdf

These are not exactly what you was looking for, but I hope can help you with your development.

Answer (score 3):

http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/demos/calendar/rrule-cajita.js?r=4000

See the test cases for usage : http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/caja/demos/calendar/rrule_test.js?r=4000

Comment: Both of those links are broken.

Comment: Looks like the example was axed.  Here are links to an earlier revision that still had the calendar example:
http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/demos/calendar/rrule-cajita.js?r=4000


Tests: http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/tests/com/google/caja/demos/calendar/rrule_test.js?r=4000

Answer (score 3):

Another implementation: https://github.com/jkbr/rrule

It's a port of Python's `dateutil.rrule` and features an extensive test suite.