# Are there any open source JavaScript/HTML recurrence rule builders for iCalendar RRules?

Tags: javascript, html, open-source, icalendar

I'm wondering, since it's such a widely used spec (i think), if there are any open source JavaScript/Html recurrence rule builders for iCalendar recurrence rules?

I mean an RFC 2445 RRULE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for javascript lib that implements RRULE (iCalendar RFC 5545)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3365981/looking-for-javascript-lib-that-implements-rrule-icalendar-rfc-5545)

Answer (score 9):

Check out [rrule](https://github.com/jkbr/rrule) which is for building recurrence rules for the iCal spec. It can also parse/serialize recurrence rules from and to natural language.